# Please advise with libcsv. I need to read only first row

Tags: c, csv, lib

I had successfully used `libcsv` to parse `CSV` files. Fast and simple to use, I tell you. But now comes a situation where I am a little stuck. Being able to parse file as whole, now I need to parse only first row.

My basic usage(not too far from the official documentation) is following:

```
typedef struct data_t {
 <...>
} data_t;
...
void cb_f(void *s, size_t len, void *data) {
...
}
void cb_r(int c, void *data) {
 ((counts*)data)->rows++;
}
...
struct csv_parser  p;
data_t             data;
...
if(csv_parse(&p, buf, fsize, cb_f, cb_r, &data) != fsize) {
 fprintf(stderr, " * while parsing file: %s\n", csv_strerror(csv_error(&p)) );
 return 1;
}
...
csv_fini(&p, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Now I need to somehow stop the parser after it had processed the first row of a `CSV` file. 
I did try to call `csv_fini(&p, NULL, NULL, NULL);` in the row callback, `cb_r`, early. No luck, the parser stops only after parsing whole buffer.

Any suggestions of how to change the `libcsv` parser operation mode ?

Comment: Use `fgets` to read a single line of the file (ie, the first row) and then call `csv_parse` with just that read data.

Comment: @kaylum won’t do because csv fields might contain newlines as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already prepared the `rows` member of struct count, you can write

```c
if ((count *)data->rows) == 0) {
  ...
} else {
  return;
}
```

in your `cb_f()` function.

You can refer to [OpenModelica](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica) to see an application of the `libcsv` library.